# Nested Json Objects and Wrapper DTO not working

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a json with the structure

```
`Object {ask: "1111111111111111111111111111111111", newrationcardapplicationdto: Object, newrationcardmemberdto: Array(1), newrationcardaddressapplicationdto: Array(2)}`
```

and a Wrapper DTO with the structure

```
 `public class NewRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NewRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO.class.getName());

    private String ask;

    public ArrayList<NewRationCardAddressApplicationDTO> newRationCardAddressApplicationDTO;

    public NewRationCardApplicationDTO newRationCardApplicationDTO;

    public ArrayList<NewRationCardMemberDTO> newRationCardMemberDTO;`
```

and controller like

`@PostMapping("/newrationcardapplication")
@Timed
@Secured(AuthoritiesConstants.DEO)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody NewRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO newRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
log.debug("REST request for New Ration Card : {}", newRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO);`

but except ask string all other nested DTOs are null.
Please guide

Comment: Log : REST request for New Ration Card : NewRationCardApplicationWrapperDTO{ask=1111111111111111111111111111111111, newRationCardAddressApplicationDTO=null, newRationCardApplicationDTO=null, newRationCardMemberDTO=null}